# Gridview: Switch from Edit to ItemMode and back to Edit by Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview with an SQLDataSource. A Click Event for a LinkButton inserts a new record in the DataBase. After that I want the Gridview to be placed into Edit Mode, with the new added record/row selected. I managed to do that:

```
    protected void AddNewMS(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXX");
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(@"Declare @NewOrderNumber int
                                             Set @NewOrderNumber = (Select TOP 1 OrderNr + 1 from EPC_Milestones ORDER BY OrderNr desc)
                                             Insert into EPC_Milestones (Active, OrderNr) Values (0, @NewOrderNumber)
                                             Select @NewOrderNumber", objConn);
        objConn.Open();
        var query = objCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        objConn.Close();
        int result = 0;
        if (query != null)
        {
            result = Convert.ToInt32(query);
        }
        Gridview1.DataBind();
        Gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
        Gridview1.EditIndex = result - 1;
    }
```

There is a checkbox in that row that gives me trouble if I check it right afterwards (Object reference not set to an instance of an object). BUT if I leave the Edit Mode. By clicking "Cancel" and enter back into "Edit" again, this checking works perfectly. I wanted to translate these 2 operations into code and therefore do Gridview1.EditIndex = -1 and back again. But it wont work. How do I completely refresh the gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Me bad... I forgot to set that label that saves the RowIndex once you enter the Edit Mode. The OnCheckedChange method of that Checkbox uses that label "SelectedMSRow" to address the correct RowIndex. So when I add a new row/record I have to adapt that label to the new Index number. So the last 3 lines of the upper code become:

```
        int RowIndex = result - 1;
        SelectedMSRow.Text = Convert.ToString(RowIndex);
        Gridview1.DataBind();
        Gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
        Gridview1.EditIndex = RowIndex;

    protected void CheckBoxCustomerRequiredChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox CheckedOrNot = Gridview1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(SelectedMSRow.Text)].FindControl("checkboxCustomerRequiredEdit") as CheckBox;
```